# How to adjust the size of a widget within a horizontal layout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout

I want all my widgets to change in length (horizontally) as I enlarge the GUI window. Right now, only the line edit changes size when I make the window larger. More than anything, I want my button and combobox to be longer.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QWidget, QListWidget, QLineEdit, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.Search_Bar = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Search")
        self.Button = QPushButton('button')
        layout = QHBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.Button)
        layout.addWidget(self.Search_Bar)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions:

- Set the same stretch by adding the widgets to the layout:

  ```
  layout.addWidget(self.Button, stretch=1)
  layout.addWidget(self.Search_Bar, stretch=1)
  ```
- Set [`QSizePolicy::Expanding`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) on the horizontal component of the [`sizePolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) button:

  ```
  sp = self.Button.sizePolicy()
  sp.setHorizontalPolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
  self.Button.setSizePolicy(sp)
  ```