# PyQt5 figure canvas doesnt stretch

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Problem is my FigureCanvas isnt taking all possible height, it is only reisizing its width. The problem occurs after resizing main window. I would like to let canvas take maximum available height.

This is how it looks now

[image: This is how it looks now]

This is minimal reproducible example:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QPixmap, QPainter, QBrush, QPen, QColor)
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Distributions")
        self.setMinimumSize(480, 320)

        # Layout
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        dirLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        radioLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        canvasLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Setting main Widget
        self.mainWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)
 

        # Setting canvas to plot
        mainLayout.addLayout(canvasLayout)
        figure = plt.figure()
        canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar(canvas, self)
        canvasLayout.addWidget(toolbar)
        canvasLayout.addWidget(canvas)
        
        plotButton = QPushButton('Plot')
        canvasLayout.addWidget(plotButton, 
        alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        plotButton.setMaximumSize(QSize(80, 60))
        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialogi = MainWindow()
dialogi.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Try removing `canvasLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)`, otherwise please provide a [mre].

Comment: It doesn't work. I've added whole code that reproduces problem

Comment: @DamianRecruit The code you provide does not generate the image you indicate, I get:  https://i.imgur.com/5JsT0H7.png

Comment: @eyllanesc it is okay as long as you dont resize window. Sorry for that

Comment: @DamianRecruit It seems that you have not understood me, in your image you show QRadioButton but in your code there is no trace of it, my DV for it.

Comment: @eyllanesc i got rid of unnecessary things to shorten my code. Anyway it doesnt affect the problem

Comment: @DamianRecruit that's not the point: you provided an image that doesn't match your code, so you should show us an image that *actually* displays the problem based on the code you gave us.

Comment: @DamianRecruit I hope that the information provided by the OP is consistent, for example, if they show me an image then the MRE should generate it, otherwise I feel "cheated". Goodbye, I'll go my way. Also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adjust the size of a widget within a horizontal layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495523/how-to-adjust-the-size-of-a-widget-within-a-horizontal-layout)

Comment: @DamianRecruit change to `canvasLayout.addWidget(canvas, stretch=1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the stretch factor when you add the widget to the layout:

```py
canvasLayout.addWidget(canvas, stretch=1)
```

Comment: Thank you really much and sorry for making makin you feel "cheated"