# how to keep layouts in a horizontal layout the same size pyqt

Tags: pyqt6

I have a pyqt app that I am working on, there is a tab where I want to split the window into two equal portions. I was using the horizontal layout to do this.
Then I made to vertical layouts for each portion. But when I expand the window it seems like the left portion expands much more than the right. Im trying to find the right method to keep them the same size while still allowing the user to expand the window. Below is the class I am using to build this and two images, one where the portions are equal and another where it is expanded and we can see the left portion is much larger than the right[image: default] [image: expanded]

(im using pyqt6, macOS, and python3.11.2)

```
class UploadTab(QWidget):
    current_user: str
    current_user_label: QLabel
    uploaded_file: QLabel
    fields: QLabel
    form_names_box: QComboBox
    left_pane: QVBoxLayout
    right_pane: QVBoxLayout
    forms: dict
    default_uploaded_file = "Press the plus icon one the left menu to add a file<img src='fugue-icons-3/icons/plus_25'>"
    table: QTableView

    def __init__(self, current_user, forms, fields, required):
        super().__init__()
        # create horizontal and vertical layouts
        horizontal_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
        vertical_layout2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
        self.left_pane = vertical_layout
        self.right_pane = vertical_layout2
        
        
        # add vertical layout to the horizontal one
        horizontal_layout.addLayout(self.left_pane)

        # widgets 1
        self.form_names_box = QComboBox()
        self.form_names_box.addItems(tuple(i for i in forms.keys()))
        self.table = QTableView()
        self.current_user_label = QLabel('<h1>' + current_user + '</h1>')
        self.uploaded_file = QLabel(self.default_uploaded_file)
        self.fields = QLabel()
        self.set_fields(fields, required)
        self.left_pane.addWidget(self.current_user_label)
        self.left_pane.addWidget(QLabel('<h2>Form</h2>'))
        self.left_pane.addWidget(self.form_names_box)
        self.left_pane.addWidget(self.fields)
        self.left_pane.addWidget(self.uploaded_file)
        self.left_pane.addWidget(self.table)

        # widgets 2
        self.right_pane.addWidget(QLabel("<h1>sup yo where am i at on this sheeeet</h1>"))
        horizontal_layout.addLayout(self.right_pane)
        self.setLayout(horizontal_layout)
        self.forms = forms
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here on stackoverflow

Answer [How to adjust the size of a widget within a horizontal layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495523/how-to-adjust-the-size-of-a-widget-within-a-horizontal-layout)

changed these lines in my code to use the stretch arg:

```
horizontal_layout.addLayout(self.left_pane, stretch=1)
..
horizontal_layout.addLayout(self.right_pane, stretch=1)
```